# Solve $\sin x+\cos x+\tan x+\csc x+\sec x+\cot x=-2$ in the interval $0<x<2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $$\sin x+\cos x+\tan x+\csc x+\sec x+\cot x=-2$$ from $0<x<2\pi$.

Could you find the most elegant solution? Does it factorize?

Comment: How about putting a = sin(x), b = cos(x) then rewrite in terms of a and b where $a^2+b^2 = 1$, a circle.

Comment: I posted the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

Writing $c=\cos x,s=\sin x$

Multiply throughout by $cs$  $$c^2s+cs^2+c^2+s^2+c+s=-2cs\iff cs(c+s)+(c+s)^2+c+s=0$$

Now,
$$cs(c+s)+(c+s)^2+c+s=(c+s)(cs+c+s+1)=(c+s)(c+1)(s+1)$$

Comment: Thank you; that's very interesting. In fact I found the factorisation (sinx+1)(secx+1)(cotx+1)=0 as well.

Comment: @Michael126, Nice to hear that. $$\sec x+1=\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x}=\frac{1+c}c$$ and $$\cot x+1=\frac{c+s}s$$

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $\sin x + \cos x=t$

Also, $t^2=1+\sin 2x$

Given reduces to :

$$\sin x+\cos x + \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
$$t+\frac{2}{t^2-1}+\frac{2t}{t^2-1}$$

$$t^3-t+2+2t=-2t^2+2$$

$$t^3+2t^2+t=0$$

$$t(t+1)^2=0$$

This is easy peasy.

Now you can easily solve the equation.

Then it's all about solving a nice trigonometry equation. You can use:$\frac{t}{\sqrt 2}=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)$

Answer (score 2):

This might be considered an extended comment of lab bhattacharjee's answer above.

The roots of the factored form are

$(\cos x + \sin x)(\cos x + 1)(\sin x +1) = 0$

which gives

$\cos x = -\sin x$. The 2 solutions are $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$;

$\cos x = -1$. The solution is $\pi$;

$\sin x = -1$. The solution is $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

So on the interval $0 < x < 2\pi$, you have the solutions $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}, \pi, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}, \dfrac{7\pi}{4}$.

**EDIT**: Thanks to lab bhattacharjee for noticing which values will be undefined if evaluated in the original equation. The the only solutions that work are $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Have you tried putting $\pi,\frac{3\pi}2$