# The smallest positive, and largest negative, values attained by $\sin x+\cos x+\tan x+\cot x+\sec x+\csc x$

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:-**

> Consider the function
>
> $$f(x)=\sin x+\cos x+\tan x+\cot x+\sec x+\csc x$$
>
> Let $P$  be the smallest possible positive real number such that the equation $f(x)=P$ has real solutions, and let $N$ be the largest possible negative real number such that the equation $f(x)=N$  has real solutions.
>
> Find the value of $[1000(P+N)]$.

**MyApproach:**

I am not getting idea how to proceed, since I can't understand how to find the real solutions. If I somehow find the smallest positive and largest negative from the real solutions, then it would be possible for me to solve this question.

> *Any idea how to get the real solutions from f(x)?*

Comment: What happened to the hint posted by @gimusi

Comment: "deleted by owner"

Comment: @Blue may I know why?Is it my fault that I have asked a bad question or his fault that he has answered incorrectly.And who is the owner of maths stackexchange?

Comment: hint: consider v=cos(x)+sin(x) and try to express the function in terms of v.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769027/solve-sin-x-cos-x-tan-x-csc-x-sec-x-cot-x-2-in-the-interval-0x2-pi and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775269/if-sin-a-cos-a-tan-a-cot-a-sec-a-csc-a-7-then-x2-44x-3

Comment: @labbhattacharjee great answer on the link that you mentioned ,I upvoted it.But here if I follow the same I would not be able to find the value of C and S since the value of $f(x)$ is not mentioned.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer: Don't worry. Your question is fine. Everything is fine. "deleted by owner" only means "deleted by author". :)  I guess gimusi simply decided the answer fell short somehow..

Comment: @Blue OK thanks for telling that.By the way if you interested in my question you can answer it,may be I will get to learn something more since you have such a high reputation.

Comment: @lab The question you post has little to do with this question. Here we are searching for range, wheres there we were looking for roots for particular value $(2)$. Maybe I am wrong who knows.

Comment: @KingTut, You are not wrong. I was trying to link related problems to the given expression.

Comment: @lab in that case you did good, methods from that question might apply here.

Comment: No time to write  up a solution right now, but solving symbolically via Maple, the values of $P,N$ are:
$$P=2+3\sqrt{2}\approx 6.242640686$$
$$N=1-2\sqrt{2}\approx -1.828427124$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\sin x+\cos x=y\implies2\sin x\cos x=y^2-1$

$$a=\sin x+\cos x+\tan +\cot x+\sec x+\csc x=y+\dfrac2{y^2-1}+\dfrac{2y}{y^2-1}$$

$$\iff y^3-ay^2+y+a+2=0$$

Now $$-\sqrt2\le y\le\sqrt2\implies-2\le-y^2\le0$$

**Case** $\#1:$

If $a\le0,$

$$0=y^3-ay^2+y+a+2\le2\sqrt2-2a+\sqrt2+a+2$$
$$\iff a\le3\sqrt2+2,\text{ but }a\le0$$

and $$0=y^3-ay^2+y+a+2\ge-2\sqrt2-2a-\sqrt2+a+2$$
$$\iff a\ge2-3\sqrt2\implies 0\le a\le2-3\sqrt2$$

**Case** $\#2:$

If $a>0$

Please try yourself , I'm yet to complete it.

Comment: Did I miss something, i don't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: How did you suddenly get the domains of y.Please add a few more steps to your answer.

Comment: @Calculus what is range of $\sqrt{2}\sin(x+...)$ ?

Comment: @KingTut, I have tried to find the possible ranges of $a$. From my hint(if my calculation is correct), $a$ can be $$\ge0$$

Comment: $$\sec x + \csc x  = \frac{1}{\cos x} + \frac{1}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x\cos x} = \frac{2(\sin x + \cos x)}{2\sin x\cos x} = \frac{2y}{y^2 - 1}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Thanks! I was also searching for the  mistake

Answer (score 0):

Period of $f$ is $2\pi$ so lets analyse it in the length $[0,2\pi]$ with the help of $f'$.
$$f'(x) = \cos x - \sin x+\sec^2x-\csc x \cot x+\sec x\tan x-\csc^2 x = 0\\
 $$

Now you have to factorise this to get the roots.

$$\frac{ (\cos(x) - \sin(x)) (  \sin(x) \cos(x) - \sin(x)- \cos(x))}{2 (\cos(\tfrac{x}{2}) - \sin(\tfrac{x}{2}))^2\sin^2(\tfrac{x}{2}) }=0$$

Now after finding the roots of $f'$, which should not be many in number, its easier to manually check for value of $f$ at these points.

I get two trivial roots as $\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}$. There are more roots from the factor $(\sin(x) \cos(x) - \sin(x)- \cos(x))$ which I havent evaluated.